# How to disable-enable submit button for dynamic file size uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have to choose file(.rdl) of dynamic size & then on submission "SUBMIT Button must disable till this has uploaded" & After uploading, it should enable if i come on the same form again.

```
if(errorFoundInData == false){    
  $('#submitButton').button('loading');         
  setTimeout(function () {    
    $('#submitButton').button('reset')    
  }, 600)
}
```

It works for less file size but if i upload large size it become disable, & enable after the set timer completed, Then i can submit the same Twice. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` method is not going work here, because you are not really sure about the file size. On success of file uploading you have to enable that.

Try something like this:

```
function doFileUpload(callback) {
  // Handle code for file uploading

  callback();// Once file upload is done trigger callback.
}

if(errorFoundInData == false){ 
    $('#submitButton').button('loading'); 
    doFileUpload(function() {
        $('#submitButton').button('reset'); 
    });
}
```

Hope this will help you to resolve the issue!